# How to override cart controller coupon action in our custom module magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm having a module which needs to override coupon code functionality

```
 <frontend>
    <routers>
        <customcoupons>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Mycompany_Customcoupons</module>
                <frontName>customcoupons</frontName>
            </args>
        </customcoupons>
        <checkout><!-- Override code starts-->
             <args>
                 <modules>
                    <Mycompany_Customcoupons before="Mage_Checkout">Mycompany_Customcoupons</Mycompany_Customcoupons>
                </modules>
             </args>
        </checkout><!-- Override code ends-->
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <customcoupons>
                <file>customcoupons.xml</file>
            </customcoupons>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

My custom module admin page working fine if i didn't add override code but if i add `<checkout>` block it show 404 page. What could be the problem? how to add override block in this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please write this in your config.XML

```
<global>
    <rewrite>
         <mycompany_customcoupons>
               <from><![CDATA[#^/checkout/cart/#]]></from>
               <to>/customcoupons/cart/</to>
         </mycompany_customcoupons>
    </rewrite>

</global>
```

Now Create File : app/code/local/Mycompany/Customcoupons/CartController.php

In CartController.php, write bellow code.

```
<?PHP

require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';

class Mycompany_Customcoupons_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{

   public function couponPostAction()
    {
         // Start You code here.
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks man :) It's working correctly after changing `<to>/mycompany_customcoupons/cart/</to>` to `<to>/customcoupons/cart/</to>` because my module `frontName` is `customcoupons`!!

Answer (score -3):

You need to add block override code into this XML. THis link will be helpful: http://magentocustom.blogspot.in/2011/05/how-to-override-magento-block-classes.html

Comment: Hi rajiv, i need to override a controller (`Mage_Checkout_CartController`) not block

Comment: everyone is talking about cart controller override but here you are talking about block override. :S